# Midlet is not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java, midlet

I am getting following message whenever I try to implement `CommandListener`. Please let me know what I need do?

> Midlet is not abstract and does not override abstract method
>   commandAction(Command,Displayable) in CommandListener

```
package displaytest;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Display;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;


public class Midlet extends MIDlet  implements CommandListener {

  private Display display = null;
  private Form form;

  public void startApp() {
    form = new Form("Hello World");
    String msg = "Hello World!  DisplayTest 12";
    form.addCommand(screen);
    form.addCommand(ok);
    form.append(msg);
    display = Display.getDisplay(this);
    display.setCurrent(form);
  }

  private Command screen, ok;

  public Midlet(){
    form = new Form("Command Form");
    screen = new Command("SCREEN", Command.SCREEN, 1);
    ok = new Command("OK", Command.OK, 4);
  }

  public void pauseApp() {

  }

  public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {
    notifyDestroyed();
  }

  public void okCom(){
    Alert ok = new Alert("OK Command", "OK Command Executed!", null, AlertType.INFO);
    ok.setTimeout(5000);
    display.setCurrent(ok, form);  
  }

}
```

Comment: The error message itself tells everything about what the problem is, and how to solve it.

Comment: If I could understand the message I would not have asked.

Comment: So, did you do any reasearch on this topic? I would suggest you to type this keyword `abstract method in Java` on Google, and learn about them. Because, you should understand the concept, rather than trying to get an answer for a specific code.

Comment: Yes, I did my research as much as I could do. If you are not willing to help at least don't try to let down people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the method that interface declares, Check [`CommandListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CommandListener.html) you need to implement the method it declares as follows

```
void commandAction(Command c, Displayable d){
 // your logic
}
```

Comment: Can you type it please. I am very new to Java.

Comment: @user1834682 Maybe that's the problem you should be fixing. Hit up a Java tutorial and read how interfaces / abstract classes work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the class abstract, or override the abstract method `commandAction(Command,Displayable)`.